# Aligning the Sidebar HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, sidebar

I am creating a Template to use for eBay listings. I have added a sidebar to float to the right of my main text body. However when I copy the source code into the eBay listing it moves away from the main text body leaving a gap with white space. How do I make it so that whatever the width of the main text body box is, the sidebar will align tight to the right of it.

I am a complete beginner to coding and I know what I have just asked probably doesn't make any sense but I have included the code below, if you open it full screen in a browser you will see what I mean.

```
<head>
   <div id="pdcontainer">    
<style>    
 #pdcontainer {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    }

 #sidebar { 
       position:relative; float:right; width:175px;
       min-height:2450px;border:5px solid #66CCFF;
    }    
 body{margin:0;padding:0;width:500px;height:2455px;border:5px solid #66CCFF;"}

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <br/><br/><br/><b><font size=+1><center></center></font></b><br/><br/><br/>
    </div>

    <div id="body"> Testfffffffffff <br/>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: First thing to try:  body{margin:0; padding:0;}

Comment: Why is there a div before the head tag? divs should be in the body

Comment: @3rror404 I have made the changes you stated and have edited my OP code to show what it looks like now. I am still having the same problem

Comment: Remove the # from #body. body isn't an ID so you don't need it. Also, you still have div before your head tag which shouldn't be there

Comment: @3rror404 - OP actually has a `<div>` with an id of "body", should be changed

Comment: @jqueryrocks Yes. Didn't notice that

Comment: OK Guys, I have edited the OP code again to show what I currently have. I made the changes @3rror404 stated. I removed the # from the body and moved the div tag inside the head.

Comment: I now have a main body and sidebar, and the sidebar is following  and aligning to right of the main body whenever I change the width. Result! However I had to remove the div I had set up for my header box as the main body was overlapping it. Any ideas?

Comment: @3rror404 I guess the div you guys are referring to is the "<div id="pdcontainer">. I copied this and the following CSS code over from another template I had in order to set up my base font settings. As I said I am a complete noob when it comes to coding and this was the only way I knew how to do it.

Comment: I have just noticed that when I enter text into the main body, when it reaches the border width, instead of returning down a line, it moves all of the text outside of the box at the bottom

Comment: @Danny You could add a CSS rule of `overflow: scroll` if you want a scrollbar for content that goes over the edges

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be this line:

```
<div id="sidebar">
 <br/><br/><br/><b><font size=+1><center></b></font></center><br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

This is not well-formed - the `<font>` tag closes inside the opening and closing `<center>` tags - I highly recommend you avoid font and center tags, but if you must use them try this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <br/><br/><br/><b><font size=+1><center></center></font></b><br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Instead of `<font>` you can use the CSS "`font-size`" property.  And instead of `<center>` you can use `text-align: center`.

Also, you should set your `<div>` elements' style to `position: relative;`

Comment: I have edited the line of code you suggested but still no luck.

Comment: Your border for #sidebar has an extra semi-colon after the 5px, and all divs should be position: relative, not just #sidebar - see if that changes anything

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/vdZGL/1/

You need to work on the formatting and structure of your code. Particularly if you're working on templates at first, just keep it simple and clean.

**Here's what I've done:**

I've renamed your `<div id="body">` to `<div id="content">` (because it makes more logical sense).

correctly wrapped the `#sidebar` and `#content` divs within the `#pdcontainer` div.

copied all of the styles that you had applied to the `<body>` and placed them in a new style for `#content`.

used `position:relative;` and `float:left;` for both the `#content` and `#sidebar` divs.

**EDIT:** Also note that you should have **no** html code with your `<head>` tags.

e.g. you have the line `<div id="pdcontainer">` in your `<head>` tags. Ensure that this line is removed and follow the jsfiddle above.